# TypeError: Cannot set property 'id' of undefined in express session(Storing session in redis)

Tags: javascript, angular, express, session, redis

Iam developing Angular4 login app. I want to store session in Redis. iam using Express session.

But I am getting the below error:

```
 req.session.id = userName;
                                               ^

TypeError: Cannot set property 'id' of undefined
```

Comment: Requires editing:  code not formatted properly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare session first

```
req.session = {};
req.session.id = userName;
```

Comment: Thanks for above answer. issue is resolved but when try to print sessionID on console. session is underfined.                                                                                     console.log("Session Id:"+ req.sessionID);

Comment: probably userName is undefined. check what is inside console.log(req.session)

Comment: it should be console.log("Session Id:"+req.session.id);

Comment: i did console.log('sessionis:' +req.session);  log output is : [object Object]. but how can i find sessionID on console ? and how do i find whether session is created and stored in redis? Appreciate your help

Comment: you do not have SessionId inside req object. it should be  console.log("Session Id:"+req.session.id);

Comment: i did the same:  console.log("Session Id:"+req.session.id); but result is undefined

1.how to get SessionId inside req object ?
2.how do i check Session is saved in Redis?

i tried using keys * in redis cli and i dont see any session.

Comment: your original question is answered anyhow. you should post a different question since i am not aware of redis